# Maven javadoc plugin in maven site not working

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I can't find any answer to this, maybe someone knows. I try to setup maven site and maven javadoc plugin but it seem to be impossible. Every time I run `mvn site:run` I get this stacktrace:

```
Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages||Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\Ignas\workspace-jedi\jedi\target\site-webapp\apidocs' dir.|
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.webapp.DoxiaFilter.doFilter(DoxiaFilter.java:145)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

And in maven site I get bunch of package does not exist errors. This thing seems not working at all, I tried various configs. Some time before I also spend a looooot of time to try this thing to work and was successful somewhat with adding  but it does not work now. I looks like impossible to setup so I need some help maybe Im missing something. I tried various variations of configs, but lets say it is default now (like found in maven site plugin documentation):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

and

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <reportSets>
       <reportSet><!-- by default, id = "default" -->
           <reports><!-- select non-aggregate reports -->
               <report>javadoc</report>
               <report>test-javadoc</report>
            </reports>
       </reportSet>
       <reportSet>
          <id>aggregate</id><!-- aggregate reportSet, for pom with modules -->
          <inherited>false</inherited><!-- don't run aggregate in child modules -->
          <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
          </reports>
       </reportSet>
  </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Am I missing something? I tried a lot of different configs but result is always the same, running a lot of symbols then that stacktrace and package does not exists errors. Maven 3.0.4 btw.

**Edit** I think i get something like this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-220 anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this config -

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

It works for me..

Comment: No that does not work. Ive tried lots of different configuration but nothing seems to work for javadoc in maven site. javadoc:javadoc seems to work ok. Actually I even see target/site-webapp/apidocs contents and it looks ok, but as I press javadoc report in generated site I always get those errors...